# Drawable crashing on Android 5 and lower

Tags: java, android, xml, drawable

So I have an XML class to give buttons rounded corners:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<gradient
    android:angle="225"
    android:startColor="#A5C938"
    android:endColor="#A5C938"/>
<corners
    android:bottomLeftRadius="7dp"
    android:bottomRightRadius="7dp"
    android:topLeftRadius="7dp"
    android:topRightRadius="7dp" />
</shape>
```

On older devices I am getting a crash stating that it is not a a drawable when I am referncing this file through: android:background="@drawable/rounded_button"

```
               Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource "com.chimesoftware.chime.chimetimemanager:drawable/rounded_button" (7f0700ae)  is not a Drawable (color or path): TypedValue{t=0x1/d=0x7f0700ae a=-1 r=0x7f0700ae}
                  at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:4017)
                  at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:3929)
                  at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:3779)
                  at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:776)
```

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/vector-drawable-resources

Comment: Thank you, very helpful, especially the part where you gave me context.

Answer (score 0):

I am checking to see if the application is now on SDK 23 and above, I found this is an error that occurs on lower SDK's.

Answer (score -1):

check in what resource package your drawable `rounded_button` is
For small screen devices it should be in `drawable-hdpi`